# showing error when accessing private property of ActivatedRoute in angular 5?

Tags: angular5

I am trying to store url paths into an array  using 'activatedRoute.snapshot.url',it works nicely by storing the url paths into an array  based on the '/' delimitor.But when I change my route into lazy loading it returns an empty array,after going through the properties of 'activatedRoute.snapshot' it returns the same results of 'activatedRoute.snapshot.url'(when using eager loading) in 'activatedRoute.snapshot._urlSegment.segments'

**output**
[image]

when I am using this property following error is shown in my terminal,but it also displays in my browser

```
ERROR in src/app/rcyc-components/rcyc-channels/rcyc-channels.component.ts(53,44): error TS2339: Property '_urlSegment' does not exist on type 'ActivatedRouteSnapshot'.
```

how can I solve this issue?Is there any other better way to get the current url paths into an array based on '/' seperator?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Location or Router services to extract URL from them.

https://angular.io/api/common/Location

https://angular.io/api/router/Router

Comment: i nedd an array it returns the path ie,if i specify '/login/home' it contains two elements login and home.

Comment: What the problem to use `split("/")` operator?

Comment: i just wanted to know is there any builtin properties of angular to get the routes in an array when using activated route?